# How to provide Jenkins pipeline resource lock label dynamically?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to figure out how to get a Jenkins resource lock to use a lock label that I have created dynamically, based on a job parameter and some additional code.

The overarching problem is that I have a complex pipeline with multiple serial and parallel steps, which needs to be locked under a single resource lock.  The resource lock label is dynamic, which is the tricky part.  The Jenkins resource lock plugin documentation says you can put multiple stages inside a lock(){} block, however this does not seem to be the case anymore.  I can only get a single script to execute inside a lock(){} block, so it seems that the lock must be placed in the top level stage's option{} block.  The problem with placing it in the option{} block, is that it does not seem possible to alter any variables used inside the option{} block from within the pipeline{} block.

For example:

```
lock_label = null

pipeline {
  agent {
    node {
      label 'ci-runner-bionic'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Setup') {
      steps {
        script {
          lock_label = 'SOME_LOCK'
        }
      }
    }
    stage('World') {
      options {
        lock label: lock_label, resource: null, quantity: 2, variable: 'SERVERS'
      }
      stages {
        stage('Something') {
          steps {
            sh 'echo "SERVERS=$SERVERS"'
          }
        }
        stage('More things') {
          parallel {
            stage('Something 2') {
              steps {
                sh 'echo "SERVERS=$SERVERS"'
              }
            }
            stage('Something 3') {
              steps {
                sh 'echo "SERVERS=$SERVERS"'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When this pipeline actually runs, the lock label that lock() sees is null, not 'SOME_LOCK'.  While it is possible to have code before the pipeline{} block that can affect the lock label, the problem is that the code that runs before does not have access to the parameters defined in the pipeline{} block.

I am aware that there is a HTTP interface to the lock plugin.  However, doing it this way may leak locks, as it cannot be guaranteed that the post block will be executed if there is some overarching Jenkins environment issue or crash.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to user build parameters as resource locks.

There is an [abandoned PR](https://github.com/jenkinsci/lockable-resources-plugin/pull/33) about it.

and and [official open issue in jenkins.](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-55771)

Comment: Official issue is closed, but not sure to understand the relationship with the problem. Do you think we can have a better solution now?